# lvm reporting wrong size after gparted expansion - Ubuntu 14.01

Tags: partitioning, gparted, lvm, resize

After realizing I had under-allocated space on a hyper-v vm for this Ubuntu install, I expanded the partition in hyper-v and then used gparted to expand the lmv and boot partitions.  However, after that, while the boot partition saw the expansion from 1GB to 5GB, the lvm partition still reports the old size of just under 5GB (though it should be 20GB).  I've attached some screen shots for review.  The item I was curious about was wondering whether or not the remainder of the lvm partition required some sort of additional formatting or something in grub to help the os realize it has a larger disk partition now.  Any help you guys can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't see any attachments - maybe just show the configuration of your volume group, logical volumes, partitioning and free space instead of a screenshot. You could indicate what you currently have and what was your expected result.

Comment: a df -h command reveals this:

Comment: Filesystem: /dev/mapper/NIO--LAB--UBUN--SBX1--vg-root  -- Size = 3.7G, Used = 2.9G, Avail = 574M, Use% = 84%, Mounting on = /

Comment: Gparted reports Mount Point NIO-LAB-UBUN-SBX1-vg as size = 19.88 Gib, Used = 4.75 GiB, Unsed 15.13 GiB

Comment: GParted would resize only the LVM Physical Volume.  To use the space within the LVM PV, you would need to resize an LVM Logical Volume within the PV with the **lvresize** command.

Comment: Thanks curtis.  I'm a bit confused on the usage syntax with resect to size and extents.  If the name of the volume I wish to resize is /dev/mapper/NIO--LAB--UBUN--SBX1 and I wish to increase its size from 5GB to 20GB, could you provide an example of what the command line syntax would look like?  Thanks!

Comment: Hoping someone else could chime in here.  As far as I can tell, my logical volume and physical volumes are set correctly, yet the operating system is still under reporting the disk size.  Here's the data that I have:  LV Path                /dev/NIO-LAB-UBUN-SBX1-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                NIO-LAB-UBUN-SBX1-vgLV Size                18.77 GiB
  Current LE             4804

Comment: OK - after much searching I finally found the series of commands necessary to do this.  http://www.geoffstratton.com/2013/08/resize-disk-ubuntu-lvm/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the last comment by Peter Lacis. See this:
http://www.geoffstratton.com/2013/08/resize-disk-ubuntu-lvm/

Basically, the partition has been resized, but you need to update the lvm and resize the file system.
So, if you've already resized the partition in GParted, then run `lvmdisplay` and note the "LV Name". Then run:

```
lvextend -l+100%FREE <lv-name>
```

Now resize the filesystem. For ext that would be:

```
resize2fs <drive>
```

where `<drive>` is something like "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--my--root".

Really, just go read the article and you'll understand better what is going on.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).